# Error while using "this" keyword in explicit intent creation

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am developing some app in which in the launcher screen , if we check a radio button it should redirect to the login activity.

In `mainactivity.java` class , during the creation of object for Implicit Intent class , the usage of `this` keyword for getting the current context is showing an error. What is the reason for this ? What else we can use for getting the context for Intent object ?

I am including my code here.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
   {
   RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
    int comp = checkedRadioButton.getId();

   if(comp==(R.id.Vitbutton))
       Intent i = new Intent(this ,LoginActivity.class);
       startActivity(i);

            }
      }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this ,LoginActivity.class);
```

to:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this ,LoginActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can Use `getApplicationContext()`

```
  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
       startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you got some suggestions about what to do better before me. But I wanna try to make you understand what is wrong:

First: did you check what Eclipse or AS says when you hover over the error? It should say sth that "the constructor of Intent class is not appliceable for using it with a RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener object"

Remember that you are in a class definiton and "this" refers to the class in which scope you are currently in. And that is "RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener"- class

you can get the "this" reference of outer class instance with "MainActivity.this" like usually in Java

Greets

Answer (score 0):

**this** is used to refered the object where this is writed.

You are tried to create a new Intent in the onCheckedChanged of the interface RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener().

Now, the costructor that you are using is Intent(Context packageContext, Class cls) BUT when you use **this** inside the onCheckedChanged you are refereing to the interface not the Activity that contain it, for this reason you saw the error.

So, in this case you can use this.getApplicationContext() or this.getBaseContext()

Answer (score 0):

When you use this inside an anonymous class, you are getting the reference for that anonymous class and not for the main class.

In this case, when you use "this", you are getting the reference for RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener and not for MainActivity (and the Intent needs the reference for MainActivity).

So you can fix it in this way:

Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this ,LoginActivity.class);

Regards.